# Logic Issue with custom binary search tree

Tags: prolog

I am trying to define a simple binary search tree. It is stored in lists like so: [Key, Left Tree, Right Tree]. I'm having issue with my logic. This is what I have

```
bstadd(K, [], [K,[],[]]).
bstadd(K, [X|_], [X, [], [K, [], []]]) :- K > X.
bstadd(K, [X, [], [K, [], []]], [X|_]) :- K < X.
```

This is what I query

```
1 ?- bstadd(19, [],T1), bstadd(20,T1,T2), bstadd(21,T2,T3).
```

this is what I get out

```
T1 = [19, [], []],
T2 = [19, [], [20, [], []]],
T3 = [19, [], [21, [], []]]
```

and this is what I need

```
[19, [], [20, [], [21, [], []]]]
```

Any help would be wonderful. I have been banging my head against the wall for days.

Comment: Using lists with fixed num.of.elements it's bad practice. Your tree would be better represented by a recursive `t(K,L,R)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution. Let me know what you think and if you find it hard to understand it I'll be glad to help you out.

```
bstadd(Value, [], [Value,[],[]]).
bstadd(Value,[Key,Left,Right],X) :- Value \= Key , % no duplicates in BST
                                    (
                                      Value < Key -> % if Value < Key
                                        % then add to left side
                                        bstadd(Value,Left,Rez) ,
                                        X = [Key,Rez,Right]
                                      ; %else (Value > Key)
                                        % then add to right side
                                        bstadd(Value,Right,Rez) ,
                                        X = [Key,Left,Rez]
                                    ).
```

Comment: I would prefer cleaner code. Inner parenthesis on `If->Then;Else` are not required. The same for the deep spacing in the body of the recursive clause.

Comment: Personally I find it much easier to read the code like this :) Is it too big a sin to leave the code like this?

Comment: It's definitely unidiomatic to have `Tree=[Key,Left,Right]` on line 1 instead of just using `[Key,Left,Right]` in the head. And `not(X=Y)` is better expressed `X \= Y`. But the spacing is not sinful (though I would use more spaces around the commas).

Comment: @ssBarBee: No, but since Prolog syntax it's a bit hostile to newcomers, I think that we should keep as simple *as possible*

Comment: Thanks for the tips Daniel,Cape. I applied some of them and hopefully it ain't hostile to newcomers anymore:)

Comment: This is great thanks a lot. Makes sense, I knew I was getting closer.